# Jquery serialize multiple form and send as JSON with different key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Hi I want to serialize the multiple forms and send it as json with different key.

I want json as

```
"{userDetails:[{'name':'Abc'}],contactDetails:[{'mobile':'123456'}]}"
```

I tried like this

```
<form id="form1">
Name : <input type="text" name="name" />
</form>

<form id="form2">
Mobile : <input type="text" name="mobile" />
</form>
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm();" value="Save" />
<script>
  function submitForm(){
        var jsonString = $('#form1,#form2').serializeArray();
}
</script>
```

Comment: `serializeArray` doesn't create JSON, it creates an array of objects. You need to call `JSON.stringify` to convert it to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

`serializeArray` creates an array of objects. If you want to put that into another object, you need to do it explicitly. And you need to call `JSON.stringify` to convert it to JSON.

```
function submitForm() {
    var details = {
        userDetails: $("#form1").serializeArray(),
        contactDetails: $("#form2").serializeArray()
    };
    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(details);
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanQ :) tried your code and runned. it is as expected :) 
https://jsfiddle.net/zuu1kbg9/1/